# Multiple 'et cetera' use

Tags: grammar, etc

Sometimes people say "etc., etc." at the end of a list to whimsically suggest many more items. Is this grammatical? Is it acceptable in a professional or academic context?

Comment: It's Latin, there is nothing more beloved in academics. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubling words for emphasis is common in English - very very common in fact. This is despite the duplication having no semantic role.

A list  finishing with etc. etc. is slightly different in that it's not exactly for emphasis, but to imply many more items, trailing off ad infinitum.

As regards usage, I wouldn't write it in a paper/thesis. I would be happy to use it in a talk, even on the slides. If your overall presentation style is at the formal/dry end of what I've seen, this might not fit so well, but if you aim more for a storytelling feel it would be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is, in an official context even:

> Queen Beatrix's **official** title was *Her Majesty the Queen of the Netherlands, Princess of Orange-Nassau, **etc., etc., etc.*** The triple 'etc.' refers to the monarch's many dormant titles. [My bold.]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatrix_of_the_Netherlands#Titles.2C_styles.2C_honours_and_arms

This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_titles_and_honours_of_Beatrix_of_the_Netherlands) shows the list not to be infinite, but it is getting there...

Comment: I question whether the occurrence of a 'phrase' in Wikipedia constitutes proper substantiation of correct usage. Wikipedia can be written & edited by anyone.

Comment: @TrevorD OK. Here's the [Dutch central bank](http://www.toezicht.dnb.nl/en/binaries/51-217291.pdf) and the [Dutch statistics office](https://www.cbs.nl/nr/rdonlyres/bbd8113d-7ee5-4be4-8879-685253b31882/0/statisticsnetherlandsactjune2013.pdf) and [UNESCO](http://www.unesco.org/culture/natlaws/media/pdf/netherlands/netherlands_act198420022009_entof.pdf) (p. 29)

Comment: Linking to a 273-page document, a 20-page document & a 10-pqge document are hardly appropriate ways to substantiate your point - and the document where you've referred to p.29 has only 10 pp.! May I suggest you amend your answer to incorporate relevant extracts from your cited documents, and then link to the source docs *with page numbers*. May I respectfully refer you to the page [How to answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and the paragraph entitled "Provide context for links".

Comment: @TrevorD I already (independently) knew the title. I then looked it up on Wikipedia, to be able to give a reference. So, I don't really feel the need to be bothered with your distrust of Wikipedia on this issue (despite me providing further evidence, for your personal satisfaction). :)